# jQuery createElement then append others inside

Tags: jquery, appendto, createelement

I am trying to customized some OS jQuery to create a div and then add the other "createElement" inside so that I can style with css. I'm out of my depth here and any help would be great. Here is my whack at the code:

```
container = $(doc.createElement(options.containerTagName)).attr({
    id: namespace + '-' + element.attr('id'),
    'class': options.containerClassName
}).insertAfter(element);

$(doc.createElement('span'))
    .appendTo(container)
    .append(element);

uploadwrapper = $(doc.createElement('div'))
    .attr('class', 'btn_upload_wrapper')
    .insertAfter(container);

$(doc.createElement('input'))
    .attr(options.buttonAttributes)
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .appendTo(uploadwrapper);

$(doc.createElement('i'))
    .attr('class', 'icon-folder-open')
    .appendTo(uploadwrapper);

textElement = $(doc.createElement(options.textTagName))
    .attr(options.textAttributes)
    .appendTo(uploadwrapper);
```

I was able to answer my own question, see below

```
container = $(doc.createElement(options.containerTagName)).attr({
    id: namespace + '-' + element.attr('id'),
    'class': options.containerClassName
}).insertAfter(element);

$(doc.createElement('span'))
    .appendTo(container)
    .append(element);

$(doc.createElement('div'))
    .attr('class', 'btn_upload_wrapper')
    .appendTo(container);

$(doc.createElement('input'))
    .attr(options.buttonAttributes)
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');

$(doc.createElement('i'))
    .attr('class', 'icon-folder-open')
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');

textElement = $(doc.createElement(options.textTagName))
    .attr(options.textAttributes)
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');
```

Comment: Was able to answer my own question. Please close this question

Comment: Why not post your answer (*as an answer*, not an edit to your question) to your question? That way it's of use to others in future; Stack Overflow's about helping others as well as yourself, to the extent that if your question *isn't* considered to be of use to other people in future it will likely be closed.

Comment: Because I asked the question before I knew or found an answer. Once I found an answer to my question I posted it as an edit and not a comment for ease reading. I hope my answer may help others who find my question.

Comment: Also, I can not answer my own question or mark it as accepted in the normal fashion because its my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to answer my own question. Please close this question

```
container = $(doc.createElement(options.containerTagName)).attr({
    id: namespace + '-' + element.attr('id'),
    'class': options.containerClassName
}).insertAfter(element);

$(doc.createElement('span'))
    .appendTo(container)
    .append(element);

$(doc.createElement('div'))
    .attr('class', 'btn_upload_wrapper')
    .appendTo(container);

$(doc.createElement('input'))
    .attr(options.buttonAttributes)
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');

$(doc.createElement('i'))
    .attr('class', 'icon-folder-open')
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');

textElement = $(doc.createElement(options.textTagName))
    .attr(options.textAttributes)
    .appendTo('.btn_upload_wrapper');
```